# Unit Test for throw Exception in Java?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

I want to create a Unit Test using JUnit in my Java app for testing the following method:

```
private void checkModels(PriceRequest request) {
    final UUID productUuid = menuService.findProductUuidByUuid(request.getMenuUuid());
    if (!menuRepository.existsByMenuUuidAndProductUuid(request.getMenuUuid(), productUuid)) {
        throw new EntityNotFoundException(MENU_ENTITY_NAME);
    }
}
```

I create the following test method:

```
public void shouldThrowExceptionWhenMenuUuidNotExists() {
    PriceRequest request = generatePriceRequest();

    when(!menuRepository.existsByUuid(request.getMenuUuid()))
      .thenThrow(new EntityNotFoundException(MENU_ENTITY_NAME));
}

private PriceRequest generatePriceRequest() {
    PriceRequest request = new PriceRequest();
    request.setMenuUuid(UUID.randomUUID());
    return request;
}
```

However, it always pass the test and I think I made a mistake regarding to setting values in the test method. So, how should I fix the problem and how should I create a unit test that method?

Comment: I'd recommend reading more about Mockito, the code you wrote is not doing anything you expect it to. For instance there is no assertion/verification.

Comment: @GaëlJ **Why vote down?** And why do not you post an example to explain your suggestions?

Comment: I didn't vote down.. there is already a good answer below.

Comment: It does not fix the problem, I have a little issue. Could you please have a look at my comments below that answer?

Comment: @GaëlJ Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test if method checkModels() will throw exception when demoService.existsByMenuUuidAndProductUuid will return  false then you can check it like this

```
private PriceRequest generatePriceRequest() {
    PriceRequest request = new PriceRequest();
    request.setMenuUuid("ABC"); // it's bad idea to always run test everytime with different values
    return request;
}


@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
public void shouldThrowExceptionWhenMenuUuidNotExists() {
    PriceRequest request = generatePriceRequest();

    when(demoService.existsByMenuUuidAndProductUuid(any()).thenReturn(false);
    
    SomeClass.checkModels(request);
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for rely, voted up. However, as the `checkModels` method is private, I cannot call it directly and I need to directly call `menuService.findProductUuidByUuid(request.getMenuUuid());` in that method. Is that true? I updated the questiıon and in some places I use repository (I think it does not make any sense in these test methods. Any idea?

Comment: Should I use `mockito.verify()`  via `@Spy` on `menuRepository`?

Comment: Any reply please?

Comment: you need to call first public method which will be in stacktrace (any that will lead to this private method). Then just mock response of menuRepository.existsByUuid(request.getMenuUuid()) to return false. Then exception will be thrown and test passes

Comment: Any update of your answer regarding to your last comment please?

Comment: Update code snippets so I can see public method which will call checkModels

Comment: What Krzysztof K is suggesting is that you could test a public or package-scope method that calls `checkModels()` .  Alternatively, I suggest just making the `checkModels()` method package-scope and testing it directly.

Comment: Thanks to all of you  for your helps.